# List objects created in current r session

Tags: r

When invoking R, it restores previous saved workspace. As I continue my work, some new objects are created and I wonder if I can list only those new objects but not the ones from previous sessions?
The command ls() will list all of them

Comment: Just erase everything with `rm(list = ls())` when you open R and then run `ls()` whenever you want. You could reload your old workspace afterwords with `restore.session(file="youoldsession.RSession")`

Comment: No you cannot as objects do not get any creation timestamp or any other attribute which would indicate when and how they were created. But you can prevent your session from being saved and loaded in first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution can be this:

Stick this statement right at the beginning of your script (or after the load statement)

```
.oldLs = ls()
```

And define this function to use instead of ls() when you want only the new values:

```
.newLs = function () setdiff(ls(globalenv()), .oldLs)
```

Note that this won't inform you if you overwrite some of the previously loaded objects in this session.